# Distinguish between clockwise and counterclockwise polygon

Tags: geometry

When using land information data such as polygons presented as arrays of points, sometimes I need to know whether a polygon's points turn clockwise or counter-clockwise. Please tell me what kind of algorithm could help with this

Comment: If the polygon is convex it is enough to check the cross product of any two given consecutive edges, treated as vectors with the same origin. For polygon $ABCDE$ it would be $CB \times CD$

Comment: Assuming your polygons are simple ("land information data" indicates this might be the case), you can calculate their signed area and check its sign, e.g. see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html).

Comment: dtldarek thank you! Why do you put a comment instead of answering? I'd mark your answer as best one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your polygons are simple ("land information data" indicates this might be the case), you can calculate their signed area as
$$A = \frac12 (x_1y_2-x_2y_1+x_2y_3-x_2y_2 + \dots + x_ny_1-x_1y_n)$$ 
and check its sign (positive means counterclockwise). The formula is found [on Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html). -- [dtldarek](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038004/distinguish-between-left-and-right-polygon#comment2115306_1038004)